# Submanifold of the space of holomorphic functions

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds

Let $H$ be the space of holomorphic functions from the unitary disk $\Delta \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}^2$ mapping $0 \in \mathbb{C}$ to $0 \in \mathbb{C}^2$. Let $x \in \mathbb{C}^2$ be a point different than $0$. Let $K$ be the subspace of $H$ made by functions whose image contains $x$. Is it true that $K$ is a codimension-$1$ submanifold of $H$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The space of holomorphic maps $\Delta\to\mathbb C^2$ is not a finite dimensional manifold. I don't know what kind of definition of "submanifold" and "codimension" that you are using.